# DLL working in WinForms but not in console application

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, console

I'm having a problem with a DLL (WisSensorNLibLib.DLL), that I use with a biometric fingerprint scanner. The thing is that the DLL methods work well in a WinForms application (such as verify a fingerprint) but as I am currently developing a console server application I wanted to use those method on that application. It doesn't show any errors, I referenced the DLL, I registered it with regsrv32 but nothing seems to get it work, every test to verify a fingerprint returns not matched... even if the sample to compare are both the same, or one received by the client app and the compare sample on the database, or even if both are hard-coded...

Is there any incompatibility with the usage of DLL and console applications? Both client app (winform) and server (console) are using .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Without specifics, it's hard to give a real answer. But the most obvious differences between WinForms and console are that a WinForms entry pointer is marked with `[STAThread]`, and that WinForms has a message-pumping loop. Your DLL might depend on one or the other or both, but I would start with adding `[STAThread]` to your `Main()` method. Of course, you should check the DLL documentation closely to completely understand what actual requirements it has.

Comment: Try setting your project to target x86 specifically instead of Any CPU, this will mean you will need to register the dll with the 32bit regsvr32 in C:\Windows\SysWow64\regsvr32.exe

Comment: Thx for your answers, I tried both and had no luck. The COM DLL documentation does not specifies anything particular, just the methods you can use. I thinking i ll be forced to migrate my solution to a winform application.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind is that when you work in winform dll calls execute from STAThread. When your application starts up, the thread of the Main method will have the MTA state.When you specify STAThread you can force that thread to get the STA state.